# RAID 0 and 1 combo?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

If I understand correctly,

RAID 1 is two drive that mirror each other, and if one fails, it can be replaced and some hours later, it's a mirror of the good drive.

Raid 0 combines 2 drives in a way that offers a speed (access) boost, but spreads data over 2 drives that can then no longer be split, i.e. you have one bigger drive with performance boost.

Can the two be combined? 4 drives, 3TB each set as two RAID 0 pairs that mirror via RAID 1. I understand that a failure then means two drives need to be pulled and replaced to rebuild the set.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's call [RAID 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID_10#RAID_1.2B0).

With 4 drives you can also do a [RAID 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID_5#RAID_5) which is more distributed than a RAID 10.

Comment: Thanks. I need to keep reading. Didn't know there was an existing method.

Comment: Depending on controllers, they even let you make a 1+0 (mirror then stripe) or 0+1 (stripe then mirror). Depending on your controller and workload the "cart before the horse" can perform differently than the usual protocol. On larger storage arrays, sometimes one or the other make sense depending more on workload and change in allocation assumptions.

Comment: I haven't tested, but at least in theory OS X's built-in software RAID can do levels 0, 1, 0+1, and 1+0. It cannot do level 5 -- that generally takes some sort of hardware-based RAID controller.

Answer (score 1):

They are correct, and depending on who you talk to it is also sometimes called RAID 10

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_RAID_levels#RAID_1.2B0

And a Mirror of Stripes can often give you the speed advantages of a RAID 0 with the redundancy of a RAID 1. But RAID 5 and 10 (I believe) require 3rd party RAID software.